# How specialize (override) class fields in Dart?

Tags: dart

I would like to *specialize fields* (override) when a `class` is *extended* or *implemented* in Dart 2.

See the code:

```
abstract class Abase {
  String id;
  List<Bbase> bbases;
}

abstract class Bbase {
  String id;
}

class A implements Abase {
  String id;
  String name;

  List<B> bbases; // 'A.bbases=' ('(List<B>) → void') isn't a valid override of 'Abase.bbases=' ('(List<Bbase>) → void').
}

class B implements Bbase {
  String id;
}
```

`class Abase` has the generic field `List<Bbase> bbase` and in the `class A` I would like to specialize this field with `List<B> bbase`.

But this is not possible. This error is presented on `analyzer` or `build_runner`:

> 'A.bbases=' ('(List) → void') isn't a valid override of
>   'Abase.bbases=' ('(List) → void').

1. Is there a reason for does not accept this specialization of fields?
2. Is there another way to specializate fields on `extends` or
   `implements`?

Comment: You can use generics but I find your code too confusing to do the actual implementation. something like `abstract class Abase<T> {
  String id;
  List<T> bbases;
}` and `class A implements Abase<Bbase> {`

Comment: Generics is the way. Great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use generics:

```
abstract class Abase<T extends Bbase> {
  String id;
  List<T> bbases;
}

abstract class Bbase {
  String id;
}

class A implements Abase<B> {
  String id;
  String name;

  List<B> bbases;
}

class B implements Bbase {
  String id;
}
```

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for.